# activity rotated in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

After closing Activity1 in landscape mode, Activity2 rotated to landscape mode for a one second and then rotate back to portrait. But Activity2 have flag `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        />
<activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />
```

Can I fix it in any way?

Comment: Try to do Activity2 forcefully portrait in Activity2 class before setContentView() :-         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari thanks, it's work!

Comment: @Dyvoker your welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

this is not related to app, when your app is in landscape at activity 1 and then you open activity 2 , Android take some time to switch between landscape and portrait as usual.